# タッチイベントについて

Tags: swift, ios

ボタンがタッチされた際、ボタンのタッチイベントとViewControllerが持つtouchesメソッドを実行させるにはどのようにしたら良いですか？

この例では、ボタンがタッチされた時、`touchesBegan`と`buttonTap`の両方が呼ばれてほしいです

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.target(forAction: #selector(ViewController.buttonTap(_:)), withSender: self)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    @objc func buttonTap(_ sender: UIButton){
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問者は回答のコメントで質問内容を変更しました > _最前面にViewを表示し、その下にボタンを表示した時Viewのタッチとボタンのタッチを両方とるにはどのよう良いですか？ 具体的には、よくソシャゲにあるタッチしている間パーティクルが出るViewを作成し、そのViewでタッチ処理をしたのですが、その下にあるボタンなどのタッチが取れずに困っています。_

Comment: @dokubeko さん、特定の回答へのコメントで「質問内容を変更」と言うのはあり得ません。元質問者さんに質問内容を編集してもらうか、(質問内容が全く異なるなら)別スレを立ててもらう等が必要でしょう。

Comment: 元の質問に対して回答したら前述のコメントがありました。回答者としては質問内容の変更以外のなにものでもありません（回答内容が動作したとかしないとか、そういったレスポンスすらありませんでしたので）。前提が変わりすぎです。質問者が自身で質問を削除しやすいよう、じぶんの回答は削除してあります（`+1`でもされると質問者が自身で削除できなくなるため）。削除にあたり、上にある通り新しい質問に当たると思われたコメントを転載しておきました。じぶんはこういった回答の労力を無駄にさせる質問者に関わる気はないのでこれ以上対処しません